# Revise Ajax Code (GIT: Lauren Gray) to work with Custom Loops

Tags: ajax, wordpress, loops

I have been using this code from Lauren Gray:

https://gist.github.com/graylaurenm/86daa4f23aa8749c0933f72133ac7106

on my Wordpress site, and it works really well for the homepage and archive loops - any that are built into the main wp_Query.  However I have created a new custom WP_Query and the AJAX doesn't work, it says "no more articles found" on click of the button...

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'paged' => $paged, 
            'posts_per_page' => 10 
        ) );


    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_content' );
        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_post_info', 12 );
        remove_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
        add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_post_image', 8 );
        add_action('genesis_entry_header','add_play_button');

        echo '<article class="' . $countClasses . implode( ' ', get_post_class() ) . '">'; // add column class
        do_action( 'genesis_entry_header' );
        echo '</article>';

        endwhile;
        if (  $loop->max_num_pages > 1 ) : 
            echo '<div class="load-more"><a class="load-more-button" id="'.$pageType.'"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Load More</a></div>';
        endif;
    endif;
```

What edits do I need to make to her code so it works with a custom loop like above?

Comment: It would be great if share all code (jQuery, Ajax code and normal listing code).